# CSS3 Transforms: Multiple Origins?

Tags: css, webkit, css-transforms

Is it possible to specify an origin at the top left (0%, 0%) for scaling, and a different origin (center) for rotation in CSS3?  I am only working with webkit, if that helps.

I am currently using a transform list (i.e. -webkit-transform: scale(newScale) rotate(newRotate)

but it seems like it isn't possible to change the origin in-between passes.  Is there a better way to look at this?  Presently, if I scale an object and rotate it with an origin at the default center, the position of the element is now off and so when you drag the element, the cursor is still at the top left of the element, whereas it should be at the center. Changing the origin to the center to scale it fixes this, but presents new problems with rotation and flipping.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Found a good solution to the problem...  by creating a parent/child relationship as follows:

```
<div class="container">
   <img src="" />
</div>
```

I can now setup two classes as follows:

```
.container {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0%;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.5);
}

.container img {
    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

This will do exactly what I want: scale with an origin at the top left, then rotate with the origin at the center.  Voila!

Comment: +1 for a solution -1 for unnecessary markup. This seems like a problem with webkit's design of these rules.

Comment: Your comment isn't helping anyone arkanciscan. It answers the question in the way it is currently implemented. Do you have another suggestion to contribute?

Comment: Note that: If the parent have `scale` then the child `transform-origin` position is still base on origin size (the size before scale)

Answer (score 1):

Instead think of the scaling with origin (0,0) as a scaling+translation with origin center.  In isolation the following:

```
-webkit-transform-origin: top left;
-webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
```

is the same as:

```
-webkit-transform-origin: center;
-webkit-transform: scale(1.5) translate3d(16.66%, 16.66%, 0);
```

In theory the rotation origin center should leave the corners sticking out by `sqrt(1/2)-0.5` requiring us to move the origin down and right by `20.71%`, but for some reason the webkit transform algorithm moves things down for us (but not quite enough) and scales the origin for us (again not quite).  Thus we need to move right by `50%` and make some adjustments for this odd behavior:

```
-webkit-transform-origin: center;
-webkit-transform: scale(1.5) rotate(45deg) translate3d(52.5%, 0.5%, 0);
-webkit-transition: all 2s ease-in;
```

Note: my original answer was using a `div` with `width:100px;` and `height100px;` which requires a `translate3d(54px, 0, 0)`.

Comment: Brett, I'm familiar with translating to move the origin, scaling, then translating back, but this one is new to me.  How does translating at the end work?  Does 54px serve as an example of the width/2 of the asset?  Sorry, trying to work my mind through this...

Comment: Notice how a scaling with origin (0,0) moves the center of the object as it scales?  Then this is the same as scaling with origin (50%,50%) while simultaneously translating the object.

Answer (score 0):

What about that: http://jsfiddle.net/22Byh/1/

Comment: That's a darn good idea, but it seems to only run the last of the two transforms.  If you bump the scalar up to 2.0+ so you can really see it, you'll notice it doesn't appear to scale.  If you change the order so scale is done second, it doesn't appear to rotate.  Am I missing something?

Comment: A it of a late comment: in css, rules are always immediately overridden, especially when in the same selector (the only 'transient' behaviour is with animations, and even then, they require different selectors). That's a fundamental behaviour of CSS, so I can't see that every changing. In fact, the nearest thing to that is repeating rule values, such as `transform: matrix(a) matrix(b) ..` - although, unfortunately, it behaves independently of other rules that also support repeated values.