# Trying to zoom image based on mouse origin, yet my math is slightly off

Tags: css, math, transform

I'm working on a full screen image viewer, I'll temporarily open a dev URL here:

http://www.jungledragon.org/apps/jd3/image/704/great_grey_owl.html/zoom

This viewer is responsive and scales to your browser width/height. One of its key features is being able to zoom in and out of the image using your mouse wheel. Rather than a center-based zoom, the idea is to zoom based on origin, meaning the coordinates of your mouse, allowing you to zoom into specific areas of the image.

**How to reproduce the issue**

If you open the above URL and have a quick play with your mouse wheel, it may appear to be working correctly. However, the math I am using is slightly off. Here is how you can reproduce the issue:

- Open the above URL
- Hover your mouse over the left eye of the Owl
- Zoom one step using your mouse wheel, it should zoom exactly into the eye
- Position your mouse on the owl's beak
- Zoom one more step using your mouse wheel

You should now notice that the second zoom step did not go into the Owl's beak exactly, it seems to be slightly off, both horizontally and vertically. I'm thinking this is a result of bad math.

**How it works**

Here is the javascript that handles it all:

http://www.jungledragon.org/apps/jd3/js/jd3-slideshow.js

I am capturing the mousewheel event. Based upon its direction, I am increasing or decreasing the zoom level. The actual zooming is nothing more than applying a CSS class that scales the image using a CSS3 transform:

```
&.grow1 { @include jd-scale(1); }
&.grow2 { @include jd-scale(1.5); }
&.grow3 { @include jd-scale(2.0); }
&.grow4 { @include jd-scale(2.5); }
&.grow5 { @include jd-scale(3.0); }
```

**Note:** the above is a call to a SASS mixin that translates into the right vendor prefixes for *transform:scale*.

The above accomplishes the basic zooming without issues. To make origin-based zooming possible, however, a few more steps are needed. Upon doing the actual zooming, I first set the **origin** of the zoom in javascript, using *transform-origin*. Here is my helper function for setting it:

```
function zoomOrigin(selector, originStr) {
selector.css({'-webkit-transform-origin': originStr});
selector.css({'-moz-transform-origin': originStr});
selector.css({'-ms-transform-origin': originStr});
selector.css({'-o-transform-origin': originStr});
selector.css({'transform-origin': originStr});
}
```

The heart of this question is about calculating the correct origin. There are two things worthy to mention in calculating this value:

- The absolute coordinates (meaning the X and Y) are relative to the image, not relative to the page
- The calculation of the origin should take into account that the image has grown/shrunk based on the current zoom state

The origin calculation happens in realtime, based on the mousemove event. Here is the method that does so, with irrelevant parts removed:

```
$("#image-container img").mousemove(function(e) {

// user has moved their mouse. in case of zooming or panning, this means that the
// origin (center point) of those interactions need to be recalculated

// calculate the mouse offset within the zoomable object (which is different than the page-level offset)
// this relies on the parent of the element having position:relative set
var parentOffset = $(this).offset();
zoomOriginX = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
zoomOriginY = e.pageY - parentOffset.top;

// recalculate the width and height of the image given the current zoom level       
width = $(this).outerWidth() + (1 + ((zoomLevelCurrent - 1)*0.5) * $(this).outerWidth());
height = $(this).outerHeight() + (1 + ((zoomLevelCurrent - 1)*0.5) * $(this).outerHeight());

// calculate origin percentages based on zoomed width and height
// the zoom methods rely on these variables to be set
zoomOriginPercX = (zoomOriginX / width * 100);
zoomOriginPercY = (zoomOriginY / height * 100);
});
```

The main purpose of this method is to correctly set the global variables *zoomOriginPercX* and *zoomOriginPercY*, which are used to set the origin (percentage) prior to zooming.

From a math perspective, my idea was to simply calculate the zoomed width of the image, and to use the offset X and Y to come to a reliable origin percentage. As the problem statement shows, I am quite close to a correct calculation, yet something is off.

Although the zooming currently works well, I want it to be perfect. It would make for quite a powerful image viewer that is really easy to implement, also for others.

Comment: So I checked your calculation for the origin, and that's working fine. Can you explain how you are measuring that the second zoom step is "slightly off"?

Comment: @EdHinchliffe Actually, my indication that it is wrong is from visually observing it. When positioning my mouse at a point in the image whilst zooming for the second time, the zoomed result is not where my mouse was at. Instead, it seems "off" by 100 or more pixels both horizontally and vertically.

Comment: Ok, I see your issue. Let me try to put it in to words in an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Desired Effect**

To start answering your question I think it's worth first clarifying the desired effect. Essentially you're looking for the same effect you'd get if you pinched to zoom on an iPhone - the 'origin' of the pinch stays exactly the same, and everything around it stretches. You can imagine pinning some stretchy fabric at the origin, and pulling the corners.

**Problem**

This is working fine for you if you don't move the mouse between zooms, but if you do, the origin appears to move. The cause of the problem is exactly that - you are changing the origin of the transform every time you move the mouse. Of course you *do* need to do this, but you are calculating the origin based on the *original* (100% zoomed) position of the image. The actual origin needs to be somewhere between the origin of the first zoom and the new mouse position.

In other words, CSS is just doing one transform. If you set the origin to x,y then zoom to zoom level 2, this will give the same result as if you set the origin to x2,y2, zoom to level 1, then move to x,y, and go to level 2.

**Solutions**

I presume you could solve the issue in several ways:

- Calculate a scaling factor for the 'new' origin on each zoom

  - this is likely a function of zoom level, mouse position and previous origin
- Calculate and apply a translation each time the origin is moved

  - again will depend on the current origin, zoom level and mouse position
- Find another way to 'stack' transforms on top of one another.

  - One way to do this may be to dynamically generate a new containing `div` each time you and apply a scale transform to that similar to the accepted solution in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8947106/css3-transforms-multiple-origins).

Unfortunately I don't have the time to go further than this, but hopefully it points you in the right direction?

Comment: Ok, I hope I understand what you are saying. I was under the impression that I did take the image scaling factor into account, but what you're saying is that I do, yet that I do not take the position-to-zoom ration into account. In other words, the new origin should be calculated based upon both the new image SCALE and the new image POSITON. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, I think so. Using your example of the eye and the beak: if you inspect the CSS after zooming first eye then beak, you'll see the origin is the same as if you zoom twice on the beak.

Comment: Thank you, if the origin is the same, that must mean indeed that the issues lies in the changed position of the image, not the actual origin. This leaves my question on the proper math open, yet at least it is more clear now what the problem is, thanks for that!

Comment: well.. if you change the way you calculate the origin you will change the position of the image when zoomed.

My first guess is to save the old (current) origin at each zoom level, then when you zoom, to make the new origin the average of the old one and the new mouse position.

Comment: I'm going to chew on this one for a while, balancing the effort and actual benefit, given that I find the current experience to at least be reasonable. I'll mark you answer as the acceptable one, thanks again.